# Why can't I reference an index of a two-dimensional list?

Tags: c++, list, compiler-errors

I know this may sound confusing, but when I use **listName[i][j]** at any point in my code, it returns an **error** saying:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E0349   no operator "[]" matches these operands
```

Here is the code where the errors appear:

```
bool BFS(list<list<int>> graph, int nodeCount, int start, int destination) {
    bool* visited = new bool[nodeCount];

    for (int i = 0; i < nodeCount; i++) {
        visited[i] = false;
    }

    list<int> queue;
    queue.push_front(start);
    visited[start - 1] = true;

    while (!queue.empty()) {
        start = queue.front();
        queue.pop_front();

        for (int i = 0 ; i < (int)graph[start - 1].size() ; i++) {
            if (graph[start - 1][i] == destination) {
                return true;
            }

            if (visited[graph[start - 1][i] - 1] == false) {
                queue.push_front(graph[start - 1][i]);
                visited[graph[start - 1][i] - 1] = true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

It seems like there is something wrong with the **first referenced index** (e.g. if I write **listName[i][j]**, the **[i]** part seems to be the problem). I cannot find anyone else having a similar problem. Am I missing something? Did I define something poorly?

Comment: You can't index into a one dimensional list using `[]`. You probably want a `std::vector`

Comment: `bool* visited = new bool[nodeCount];` -- 1) Your code has a memory leak because of this and 2), why didn't you use `std::vector<bool>` here?  If you knew enough to use `std::list`, why not `std::vector` for this obvious situation?  That indicates you may just be getting code from some (very poor) website, without inspecting it properly.  If this is the case, you won't learn C++ properly this way.

Comment: `list<list<int>> graph` -- This should be passed by reference, not by value.  Yet another obvious oversight.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use **operator[]** with **list<list> graph**. **std::list** doesn't support **operator[]**.
If you want an index based element retrieval, you can you **std::vector** instead.